# Next.js app will not auto refresh to show changes in the browser even though im running npm run dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, next.js

I want to see any updates i make to my code reflected in the browser. In VSC terminal I run "npm run dev". If i make changes to the code nothing happens unless i CTRL + C and run "npm run dev" again.

I have tried running it in Chrome (instead of Brave)

I have tried:

```
npm run build
npm start
```

I have tried:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": " next dev -p 8000",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
  }
```

I have tried:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": " next dev -p 8888",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
  }
```

im wondering if it has to do with the way ive organized my project

below is my project's directory organization:

```
v components
 v web3
  Connected.js
  NotConncted.js
  Web3Button.js
 DashboardSidebar.js
>node_modules
>pages
 >api
 _app.js
 index.js
...etc
```

[image]

Comment: Turn caching off, set no-cache this is just to spare your server some bandwidth if its served the file already it can have a time to live for a while before needed to recheck source.

Comment: where would i set no-cache

Comment: Not sure of Next.JS; but you'd set this in your app as a HTTPS header when serving files. If you want to properly fix things, you can insert your javascript/modified files like this yourfile.js?v=1.0.0 and when you revise change the version.